# What has been the experience in making a mobile app using phonegap and CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, cordova, codeigniter-2

I'm looking at making a mobile app using phonegap. However, I would like to use CodeIgniter as well. What has been the community's experience in doing such? I have tried googling it but only seem to find resumes and job wanted ads! I intend to use CI with jquery-mobile. But I was wondering if i could use phonegap with it and package it as a android or iOS mobile app.

Comment: Please rephrase the question. "Has anyone else tried X" is [not a real question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using CI as your backend to deliver data back and forth between your mobile app built with phonegap + jquery mobile.  If that is the case, whether you use CI or any other backend web framework, it should be pretty straight forward.  You'll probably want to consider using JSON as your data format to keep data size down.

I would imagine RESTful web services would suit you well.  Check out this guide on getting them working in concert with CI: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

I personally am using a CI + phonegap + xuijs stack now and its pretty straight forward in terms of communication.